# Aplicar expresiones regulares en BOT de Autorespuestas

Tags: java

Se trata de configurar un BOT de respuestas automáticas con un app Android llamada Autoresponder (java regular expression)

CONTEXTO: Necesito ingresar algunas expresiones regulares para lograr que el BOT responda mensajes cada vez que detecte ingresadas las palabras claves asignadas a cada pregunta

En conclusión, Reconocer líneas de texto (preguntas de usuarios) a través de una o varias palabra claves.

EJEMPLO
usuario1: Puedes decir algunos ingredientes para hacer jugo de limón?

Usuario2: que jugo puedo hacer con la fruta limon?

Usuario3: que jugo puedo aporta vitamina C al organismo?

RESPUESTA DEL BOT: Mmm... Jugo de limón! Los ingredientes del jugo son limón, azúcar y agua. Ahora exprime varios limones en un litro de agua y endulza moderadamente. Alto en vitamina C.

(Solo tengo esto)

`/.*(limón|limon|vitamina C).*`

Pero necesito que haga match independientemente de que las palabras claves sean mayúsculas, minúsculas o tengan tilde! Ya me explotó la cabeza

Gracias por leer tanto!

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido, ayudanos a ayudarte, para lograrlo necesitamos que detalles exactamente que palabras quieres reconocer, y el contexto asociado, y para saber que formas parte del intento de encontrar la solución... muéstranos que has intentado, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Gracias muchachos! Ya edité! Estoy atento

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Lamento incomodar, si llegué aquí es porque no sé nada de esto! Solo quise ayuda para hacer el proyecto de mi hijo! Eliminen la pregunta porque no entiendo muy bien los requisitos para consultar!

Answer (score -2):

Se que esta no es la respuesta que pediste, quieres un regex, y esto no lo es, sin embargo, creo que este enfoque, te permite alcanzar el objetivo, y es mucho más fácil de modificar/adaptar a  distintos requerimientos.

```
boolean verifica( String textoEntrada, String claves[] ) {
   String sinAcentosNiOtros = Normalizer.normalize( textoEntrada, Normalizer.Form.NFD ).replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" ).toLowerCase();
   for( int i = 0; i < claves.length; i++ ) {
      if( !buscarPalabra( claves[ i ], sinAcentosNiOtros ) ) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}    
   
boolean buscarPalabra( String palabra, String palabras ) {       
  String regex = "(^|[\\W]{1})(" + palabra + ")([\\W]{1}|$)";
  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( regex );
  Matcher matcher = pat.matcher( palabras );
  if( matcher.find() ) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

String claves[] = { "limon", "vitamina c" };
String textoEntrada = "Quiero saber como ganar vitamina C, sirve tomar jugo de limón?";
if( verifica( textoEntrada, claves )) {
   hagoAlgo();
}
```

La solución que propuse, tenía serios problemas, modifiqué la forma en que busca coincidencias, para evitar que diera falsos positivos, manteniendo la idea de que con solo modificar el array **claves**, puedes modificar lo que se busca, haciéndolo reutilizable, permitiendo hacer busquedas de mayores cantidades de palabras claves sin esfuerzo, sin tener que crear un nuevo regex para cada una.

El regex que uso, está dividido en tres bloques, el primero usa un **`or`**, para verificar que la clave, o bien sea la primera palabra del texto, o esté precedida de cualquier cosa que no sea un caracter alfanumérico, el segundo captura la palabra clave, y el tercero (similar al primero) determina si es la última palabra del texto o está seguida de un "no-alfanumérico".

Edición número no se cuanto:

Haciendo una pequeña modificación, nos permite hacer búsqueda sobre palabras y sus sinónimos.

```
String claves[][] = {
    { "limon", "limones" },
    { "vitamina c" }
};

boolean verifica( String textoEntrada, String claves[][] ) {
   String sinAcentosNiOtros = Normalizer.normalize( textoEntrada, Normalizer.Form.NFD ).replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" ).toLowerCase();
   for( int i = 0; i < claves.length; i++ ) {
      boolean salida = false;
      for( int j = 0; j < claves[ i ].length; j++ ) {
         if( buscarPalabra( claves[ i ][ j ], sinAcentosNiOtros ) ) {
            salida = true;
         }
      }
      if( salida == false ) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```